# Painting Background with respect to Rescaled Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I want to create a poster with a genealogy tree on it. So far, I managed to create the tree and resize it with a resizebox to an appropriate height. Now, I would like to colour the background of the entire page in different colours, and the coordinates of this colouring depend on the genealogy tree. In the MWE below, I coloured the bounding box of the resized tikzpicture in grey and yellow, with the line between grey and yellow at a height that has been determined by the tree. I would like to extend this colouring to the entire background.

The problems I have encountered are as follows:

- If I paint the background in a separate tikzpicture, I cannot access the nodes of the tree, because of the resizebox.
- `autosizetikzpicture` from the `genealogytree` package has the same problem
- If I simply make the picture very big by adding nodes that go beyond the page, I create an overflow and get a white page before the actual poster.

Any ideas are welcome. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size = a0,orientation = portrait]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0mm}

\begin{document}%
    \centering%
    \phantom{}
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    \noindent\resizebox{!}{.97\paperheight}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
        \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
            parent{
                g[id=a1]{a1}
            parent{
                g[id=a2]{a2}
            parent{
                g[id=a3]{a3}
            parent{
                g[id=a4]{a4}
            parent{
                g[id=a5]{a5}
            parent{
                g[id=a6]{a6}
            parent{
                g[id=a7]{a7}
            parent{
                g[id=a8]{a8}
            parent{
                g[id=a9]{a9}
            parent{
                g[id=a10]{a10}
            }}}}}}}}}}}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[black!60] (current bounding box.south west)  rectangle (a5-|current bounding box.south east);
            \fill[yellow!55] (a5-|current bounding box.south west)  rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two (and a half) changes:

- instead of drawing the background from the corners of the `current bounding box`, you can use the corners of the `current page` (requires the `remember picture` option)
- to avoid an additional white page due to the picture not fitting in the text area, you can use the `overlay` option for the background paths.
- (I would always use a `frame` environment with beamer, even if you only produce a one-page document. This will safe you from hacks like manually adding vertical space at the top)

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size = a0,orientation = portrait]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0mm}

\begin{document}%
\begin{frame}
    \centering%
    
    \resizebox{!}{.97\paperheight}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
        \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
            parent{
                g[id=a1]{a1}
            parent{
                g[id=a2]{a2}
            parent{
                g[id=a3]{a3}
            parent{
                g[id=a4]{a4}
            parent{
                g[id=a5]{a5}
            parent{
                g[id=a6]{a6}
            parent{
                g[id=a7]{a7}
            parent{
                g[id=a8]{a8}
            parent{
                g[id=a9]{a9}
            parent{
                g[id=a10]{a10}
            }}}}}}}}}}}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[black!60,overlay] (current page.south west)  rectangle (a5-|current page.south east);
            \fill[yellow!55,overlay] (a5-|current page.south west)  rectangle (current page.north east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you. Here I go facepalming myself - I tried current page with various other options before I settled on resizebox. It never occured to me that with remember picture and resizebox in place, it might actually work.

Comment: @TTLx You're welcome!

Comment: Oh, I see. `overlay`.

Comment: @cfr ... a very useful option :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Indeed. I couldn't figure out why your solution worked until I noticed that. I came up with something different. Do you know why the tree disappears in the first place?

Comment: @cfr Nice answer! I did not run into the problem with a disappearing tree, so hard to diagnose.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh, really? That's very odd. Every time I extended the background to the page boundary, the tree disappeared completely. I wonder why.

Comment: @cfr Maybe some temporary effect from changing the coordinates? I normally compile with latexmk, so I usually only see the result once all the coordinates have settled.

Comment: Hmm. It definitely didn't settle with only 2. There's something weird about the resizing interacting with it when you don't use `overlay` or take it out of the bounding box. It's just odd. Or I'm being very stupid, which is far more likely.

Comment: @cfr I just tried again without the `overlay` and while the three does not completely disappear, it is not scaled correctly, which is probably the scaling and the absolute coordinates of the background working against each other. I guess it might depend on the starting point if the tree vanishes completely... The text margins might also prevent the background from being where it should be.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for investigating. That sounds plausible and a bit less odd. I would expect it to affect the scaling, though it still seems a bit weird it would have such a dramatic effect given the difference between 0.97 and 1 can't be that huge, but perhaps it is a width thing.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not unlike [samcarter's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701232/). `current page` provides the nodes, but doesn't solve the difficulty. One of the problems, I think, is that because the background is inside the box being resized, you end up resizing the background. For example, you always get white margins at the top and bottom because the background is resized to 97% of the paper height.

Another problem is that, for reasons I don't understand, this also causes the tree itself to disappear. I thought this might be due to `genealogytree`'s use of `background`, but that's evidently not the case. The documentation has examples using the standard `background` layer and creating an additional layer behind *that* for the background doesn't resolve the issue.

So this suggested part of the problem might be that the background is getting resized. The obvious solution is not to resize the background. Rather than using `overlay` (which didn't occur to me), I simply told `tikz` not to take account of the background when calculating the bounding box of the picture.

The use of `remember picture` is still required here for the `current page` nodes to work correctly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size = a0,orientation = portrait]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\let\mypgfrelevantforpicturesizefalse\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse
\let\mypgfrelevantforpicturesizetrue\pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0mm}

\begin{document}
\centering
\phantom{}
\vspace{1cm}

\noindent
\begin{autosizetikzpicture}[remember picture]{}{.97\paperheight}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
    parent{
      g[id=a1]{a1}
      parent{
        g[id=a2]{a2}
        parent{
          g[id=a3]{a3}
          parent{
            g[id=a4]{a4}
            parent{
              g[id=a5]{a5}
              parent{
                g[id=a6]{a6}
                parent{
                  g[id=a7]{a7}
                  parent{
                    g[id=a8]{a8}
                    parent{
                      g[id=a9]{a9}
                      parent{
                        g[id=a10]{a10}
                      }}}}}}}}}}}
  
  \mypgfrelevantforpicturesizefalse
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[black!60] (current page.south west)  rectangle (a5-|current page.east);
    \fill[yellow!55] (a5-|current page.west)  rectangle (current page.north east);
  \end{scope}
\end{autosizetikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Although I didn't here, I'd also recommend using `frame` for content in `beamer`. For one thing, it makes it easier to apply `modes` and to leverage the class's various features.

[image: background filling behind tree]